# There is an overload of this function

Tags: ajax, jquery

I need a simple overload of the method

```
   $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Footer")',
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            $(".maindiv").append(result);
        }
    });
```

example `$(".maindiv").append(ajax.loader('@Url.Action("Footer")'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that because the result of `ajax` is asynchronous. When the function returns, there is nothing to append. That's the reason why we give callbaks to `ajax`.

In fact, you **could** do it, by returning a placeholder and defining a success function replacing the placeholder, but :

- this would be heavy and ugly
- the fetched content still wouldn't be present at next instruction
- there would be no advantage over the usual practice

The real thing to do is to understand the asynchronous event based logic of javascript in the browser and learn to deal with it.